# Registering Elasticsearch Script

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

Is there any way how to register script in ES?

Let's say I have script in painless and I want to send it to server and then call it in code.

Comment: Are you talking about [stored scripts](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting-using.html#modules-scripting-stored-scripts)?

Comment: Oh yes, something like this. Thank you!

Comment: Is possible to define functions inside painless scripts?